# MikTex Crashes on Update

Tags: miktex, updating

I've recently started writing a long academic paper and some other problems forced me to update MikTex to a current version. I ran the Updater (Admin) several times. Now I have two issues. The TeXworks gui has horribly oversized fonts in its user interface, the fonts are over the top big. But I could carve my eyes out and live with that. The main problem is that when a package is missing (e.g. the `url` package in this case), the install package dialog pops up during compilation and upon clicking ok, crashes pdflatex. If I try adding the package via Package Manager (Admin), I get the following crash:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77d4dd10 in mpm_mfc_admin.exe: 0xC06D007E: Module not found.

Any idea which module might be missing? This is just another problem on top of many problems. I gradually destroyed my document and now also the MikTex installation ... great. I should get a job in the industry.

**EDIT**

When running from Texworks, I can also see the following texify log:

```
2016-01-06 22:35:38,101+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-01-06 22:38:36,070+0100 FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason (see log file).
2016-01-06 22:38:36,070+0100 FATAL texify - Info: 
2016-01-06 22:38:36,070+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2016-01-06 22:38:36,070+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 1452
2016-01-06 22:39:15,023+0100 FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason (see log file).
2016-01-06 22:39:15,023+0100 FATAL texify - Info: 
2016-01-06 22:39:15,023+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2016-01-06 22:39:15,023+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 1452
2016-01-06 22:39:59,289+0100 FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason (see log file).
2016-01-06 22:39:59,289+0100 FATAL texify - Info: 
2016-01-06 22:39:59,289+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2016-01-06 22:39:59,289+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 1452
2016-01-07 09:48:48,398+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-01-07 10:11:36,304+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-01-07 10:12:31,617+0100 FATAL texify - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
2016-01-07 10:12:31,617+0100 FATAL texify - Info: 
2016-01-07 10:12:31,617+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\MemoryMappedFile\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp
2016-01-07 10:12:31,617+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 155
```

And the error is the same:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77d4dd10 in pdflatex.exe: 0xC06D007E: Module not found.

Comment: Check carefully that you have all new packages and updates by synchronizing and using the package managers. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490

Comment: Yes. I have ran the updater several times, now the list is empty. Bad timing, I dont like it. How can I go to the working pre-dezember 2015 miktex?

Comment: I didn't wrote "update manager" but "package manager". Did you actually read the answer I linked to?

Comment: Oh, right, my bad. Except that I can't install any new packages (did you read my question?). Also I somehow doubt that Swedish hyphenation package is helping my problem in any way.

Comment: Your question says something about "if I try updating the package via Updater (Admin),", nowhere is mentions the package manager.

Comment: Well, I was mentioning the problem of adding a missing package which should have been manager rather than updater. Anyhow, I need to write this thing. Is there a way to get the old version miktex? Yes or no?

Comment: I also tried reinstalling from scratch, which sadly did not help my issue.

Comment: No you can't go back (unless you made a backup before you clicked the update button). You probably updated some binaries and didn't got the necessary dll first. *I* would try to repair it by trying to install from the command line or manually after getting the packages from CTAN. Try texlive if you don't get miktex to work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm ditching MikTex for good. Will probably go with overleaf or something else that works. Thanks for your help.